# get screenshot from video using ffmpeg

Tags: wordpress, ffmpeg

I'm building a Wordpress site that allow admin to upload and attach a video clip to a post. After the video was uploaded successfully, I use ffmpeg to get a screenshot from that video, and that screenshot would be the post featured image.

In my case, the screenshot was generated successfully. In next step, I use Wordpress function media_sideload_image() to copy that screenshot to WP 'uploads' folder and make that image as post featured image.

But for some reasons, the media_sideload_image() returned a WP_Error: http_404. I have checked the url of the temporary screenshot image, but it was valid and display a screenshot nicely.

In this case, I guess that the media_sideload_image() was called after the ffmpeg command, but at that time, the ffmpeg process has not completely finished so the media_sideload_image() encountered http_404 error.

So the question is: Is there any way to make sure the screenshot was saved completely before running media_sideload_image() function after that, to avoid http_404 error ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if its even possible to check whether the file was completely saved or not. But you can check if the image file exists.

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    media_sideload_image($file, $post_id, $desc);
}
```

It should solve the problem but if for some reason it takes longer to fully save the file, you can add a delay for a few seconds.

```
sleep(2); // 2 Second delay before checking and saving the file.
if (file_exists($file)) {
    media_sideload_image($file, $post_id, $desc);
}
```